Identify optimal product size configuration based on historical data and some constraints
We have historical data for the demand of a product. Product can be demanded in any quantity between 0-1000g and the historical data show the distribution of previous request sizes. We can only pack the product in 5 sizes. To a meet a request, we can use combinations of the sizes in the inventory with the following rules:

Sizes can be repeated to match the requested amount
If exact amount of request cannot be met using the sizes available, you can over distribute but not beyond 10% of the requested amount (hard constraint).
Minimize the number of packages used to a meet a demand
If two solutions have same number of packages and satisfy all the other constraints, then use the solution with minimum over distribution

Given the rules above for product distribution and previous demand data, can we identify ideal 5 packing sizes.
Example illustrating the rules:

If demand is 8 and the sizes are [1,2,5], we can give 8 1s or 4 2s or 5+2+1. Based on the rules, we need to minimize the packets, hence 5+2+1 is distributed.
If demand is 13 and the sizes are [1,2,5], we can overdistribute and give 5+5+5 to meet the rules.


"minimize..." is not a constraint, it is an objective function.  I don't understand what it means to "relax" an objective function.  What do you mean by "
packing sizes"?

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $D=\{1,\dots,1000\}$ be the set of demands.  For $d\in D$, let $f_d$ be the historical frequency of demand $d$.  Let $S=\{1,\dots,1100\}$ be the set of possible sizes.  For $s\in S$, let binary decision variable $x_s$ indicate whether size $s$ is selected.  For $s\in S$ and $d\in D$, let nonnegative integer variable $y_{sd}$ be the number of times that size $s$ is used to satisfy demand $d$.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{s\in S} \sum_{d\in D} f_d y_{sd}$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{s\in S} x_s &\le 5 \tag1\label1 \\
d \le \sum_{s\in S} s y_{sd} &\le 1.1d &&\text{for $d\in D$} \tag2\label2 \\
y_{sd} &\le \left\lfloor\frac{1.1d}{s}\right\rfloor x_s &&\text{for $s\in S$ and $d\in D$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} selects at most $5$ sizes.
Constraint \eqref{2} satisfies demand $d$ without oversatisfying beyond 10%.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces the logical implication $y_{sd} > 0 \implies x_s=1$.

This is great, thank you! One edge case: when y_sd is the same for two possible solutions, we want to choose the solution with minimum overdistribution. Example: s =[1,2,5] and d =6 and overdistribution limit is 5%, then 5+2 or 5+1 meet all the requirements in the above formulation. However, we want to pick 5+1 as overdistribution is zero.

@user896201 The minimization objective will naturally do that.

As the objective function value is the same for both the solutions mentioned above (y_sd = 2) and all the constraints are satisfied in the two scenarios, I wonder how the formulation above would get the desired solution of the one with minimum overdistribution?

Sorry I misunderstood. In the example from your comment, $\sum_s y_{sd}=2$ for both solutions. To break the tie, you can use a secondary objective of minimizing $\sum_s \sum_d s y_{sd}$.

You can try:
With variables $x_s$ over $s=\{1..5\}$ and $y_{s,d}$ over $s$ & demand $d$ and $\in Z^+$
$\min \sum_{s,d} f_d y_{s,d}$
s.t.
$d \le \sum_s x_s y_{s,d} \le 1.1d \quad  \ \forall d$
Th above formulation will however introduce non-convexity in the constraint.
